# Focus on textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have just put some css on a textbox :

```
 #TxtBoxDescription
{
height: 30px;
padding: 5px;
width: 185px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
border: none;
float: right;
margin: 10px 3px;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

 #DropDownListPriority
{
float: right;
height: 30px;
width: 95px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
margin: 10px 3px;
}

  #LkAddBug
 {
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
font-family: 'Quicksand' , sans-serif;
float: right;
width: 95px;
height: 22px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
margin: 10px 10px 10px 3px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
letter-spacing: -1;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

And now when I want to click on the textbox to write some text, I can't click on it in the middle, I have to click on the bottom to get the focus ... That is so weird, so I think it might be a css problem but I can't fix it ... Can someone help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: an live example in http://jsfiddle.net/ is good for understanding your problem

Comment: Are there a lot of other controls on the page? Did you test it by putting it on a blank page without any other controls? I reminds me of another control which (not visually) overlaps your textbox.

As a test, add a large z-index to your CSS of the textbox. Something like z-index: 100000;

Comment: I am also floating a drop down list and a Link button . Edited in my post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVEJq/1/), that CSS doesn't affect either a textarea or text input. Tested in both IE and Firefox.

You either have something else which is causing your problem or you've missed out a pertinent piece of information.

Comment: Ok i fixed it ! I had to add position relative ! Strange ... But working !